# How to make tikz help lines have the (0,0) start exactly at lower left corner of the body of the page?

Tags: tikz-pgf, grids

Is there a way to automatically make help lines that spans the whole body of the page where `(0,0)` at south west corner of the page? Here is a MWE. I did this by trial and error and found that `(0,0) grid (18,24)` almost does the job, but it is not exactly a good fit.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm, showframe]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[help lines, gray, dashed, step=1] (0,0) grid (18,24);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

First, here is latex page geometry

[image]

And this is the output of the code above

[image]

The default spacing unit is 1 cm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz, tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm, showframe]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture, shift={(current page text area.south west)}]
\draw[help lines, dashed] (0,0) grid (current page text area.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Page with dashed grid]